# WPF datagrid row details peek (layers)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i am looking for a way to quickly peek into collapsed row details in DataGrid.

when a user mouses over the rows, there should be a quick peek layer next to the cursor that would have a summary of what is in details. Ultra fast is key here.

looking for something equivalent to layered div in DHTML. No transparency effects needed.

From what i've seen on this forum, this is not inherently supported? i'd need to show a separate window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `ToolTip` property of the row?

```
<DataGrid Name="_grid">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item3}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

...where `Item3` is a property you want to display (I used a simple Tuple as `ItemsSource`). You'll probably have more complicated content of `DataTemplate` and `ToolTip` of course but this should give you an idea.